Formula to return a value when the adjacent column's text contains any value from an array of text strings
In Google Sheets I have an array named "Tech_issues" with the following values:



Array name
value 1
value 2
value 3
value 4




Tech_issues
crash
froze
glitch
error



I'm looking to create a formula in column B that I can use to return value X if the corresponding cell in column A contains one (or more) of the words in the array, for example...



Survey response
Tech issue




system crashes way too often
X


I encountered an error
X


Nice design



Sell more products




There are other arrays and queries I want to use for other columns as well, this is just one example so if I can get this working I can do the rest.
So far I've tried the following but to no avail...
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,Tech_issues), "X", "")

=isnumber(search(Tech_issues,A2))

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Tech_issues, A2)),"X","")

=ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(A2, JOIN("|",Tech_issues)))

HELPPPPP

This is an array formula that will return all the values or a blank for an entire column.
=INDEX(
   IF(
     REGEXMATCH(
       A2:A, "(?i)"& JOIN("|", Tech_issues)), 
     "X",))

To return only a single row use,
=INDEX(
   IF(
     REGEXMATCH(
       A2, "(?i)"& JOIN("|", Tech_issues)), 
     "X",))


Tech_issues should be a named range or a reference to a range containing your keywords eg. B2:B10
(?i) is prepended to make the regular expression case insensitive.

